# Rails PDFKit not rendering d3 javascript on download

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, pdf, d3.js, pdfkit

NOTE: I am NOT using the PDFKit Middleware. I am using PDFKit as a way for users to Download a PDF of the page they are looking at, no middleware involved whatsoever, no viewing PDF within the browser.

I have a javascript-heavy view--in particular D3.js. I am using D3 to create a bunch of fancy charts and I want the user to be able to download a PDF of it.

Here is my controller method in the Reporting controller:

```
def download_pdf
  @charting_group = ChartingGroup.find(params[:charting_group_id])

  @html_file = render_to_string("reporting/charts", :layout => false)
  kit = PDFKit.new(@html_file)
  kit.stylesheets << '/root/absolute/path/to/app/assets/stylesheets/pdfkit.css'
  send_data kit.to_pdf, :filename=>"test.pdf", :type=>"application/pdf", :disposition=>"attachment"
end
```

The view, (reporting/charts.html.haml) is a relatively empty view with just a couple H2 tags and empty divs. The d3 code then selects those divs and makes a bunch of beautiful charts inside them with this code:
(from reporting/charts.html.haml)

```
=link_to 'Download PDF', reporting_download_pdf_path(:charting_group_id=>@charting_group.id)
.row
  .small-12.large-12.columns
    %h2
      Charts by Category
    #byCategory

.row
  .small-12.large-12.columns
    %h2
      Charts by Subcategory
    #bySubcategory

:javascript
$(document).ready( function() {
  var url = "/reporting/graphs.json?charting_group_id=#{@charting_group.id}"
  d3.json(url, function(error, json) {
    if (error) return console.warn(error);

    byCategory(json.byCategory);
    bySubcategory(json.bySubcategory);
  });
});
```

the byCategory() and bySubcategory() functions are defined in byCategory.js and bySubcategory.js respectively and are 100% d3 code which selects the #byCategory and #bySubcategory divs and appends a bunch of SVG bar charts using the data from "/reporting/graphs.json?charting_group_id=#{@charting_group.id}".

Now, when I click my Download PDF button, wkhtmltopdf fires up, generates the pdf, my browser downloads it, *and the PDF is just the bare-bones charts.html.haml page with no d3 charts!*. The PDF has a couple of H2 tags that say "Charts by Category" and "Charts by Subcategory" and thats it, so it is not picking up the d3 whatsoever. That is my problem.

Does anyone know why this is? Or what I can do? Here are a few things I've tried:

1. I have tried moving all the code (all the d3 code, and all the json
   data) into the charting.html.haml view and while it still works fine
   on the website, clicking Download PDF still gives me a near-empty
   PDF.
2. I have tried changing the render_to_string to
   "reporting/charting.html.haml" which gave me the exact same result.
3. I have tried changing the render_to_string to
   "/reporting/graphs.json?charting_group_id=#{@charting_group.id}"
   which gives me an error.

NOTE: the generated PDF picks up the pdfkit.css style sheet just fine; When I change the color of the h2 tags in that stylesheet, the generated PDF reflects those changes.

I know that wkhtmltopdf can handle d3 because I've made many PDFs from d3-heavy sites before using it from the command line.

Notes about my environment:
Mac OSX
pdfkit (0.5.4)
wkhtmltopdf 0.9.9
Rails 3.2

Any help or advice that anyone can lend is greatly appreciated :) thank you

**UPDATE**

Testing the possibility that the pdf is generating before the ajax call, I tried making a config/initializers/pdfkit.rb with this in it:

```
PDFKit.configure do |config|
  config.default_options[:redirect_delay] = 20000  
end
```

This made the whole "process" of PDF generation much much longer, but when finished I had the exact same result as before :(

Comment: PDFkit is generating the PDF before your Ajax call finishes and thus the d3 code is never run. I ran into this same issue and ended up using phantomjs.

Comment: What @benr said sounds like reasonable explanation to me.

Comment: That is what I originally thought, however I tested that by cutting out all ajax requests and putting all the code inside the html.haml file in a script tag. Including the json data, I pasted the entire json blob into the file and assigned it to a variable within that code and got the same result.

Comment: Could it be that despite that, the pdf is still generating before the d3 has time to render?

Comment: Hmm, one more thought. Perhaps PDFKit doesn't try and render the html as 'page' if it's given a string like you do. Thus no amount of delay will make the javascript execute. Try using your actual Rails route (ie localhost:3000/reporting/charts) as the first argument.